# Different kinds of hardening abilities

Tags: attack-on-titan

Ok, as far as I know, there are 3 types of hardening.

- White hardening = Jaw and Warhammer
- Blue/Crystal hardening = Female, Attack and Beast
- Natural hardening = Armored

My question now is, are those abilities combinable if those are different kinds of hardening?
Like could the armored, jaw, or the Warhammer also be able to have additional crystal hardening?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing called "white" hardening, Warhammer hardening is crystal type, like female or attack titan, and Jaw hardening is neither natural nor white(crystal), but it looks like the natural type. so because armored titan is the only titan that can do natural hardening, there won't be any hardening combination.

**EDIT** :
I was wrong about Warhammer's body, it **IS** hardening but I don't think it's different from other types of hardening

Comment: Why are they shown so differently then?

Comment: @DieserCoookie you'll understand if you pay more attention, Warhammer titan whole body and weapons are white, it's NOT hardened. the only hardened part is the wielder's body which is crystal. Annie's hardening, Eren's fists, all of them are the same crystal, the only difference is their color which I don't think is an important subject to put your mind into, it's like titans eyes, for someone it's purple(
Frieda Reiss), green(eren jager) and etc

Comment: Just to point out that Warhammer's body does have `hardened` titan covering/skin/flesh

But yes, the hardening don't have types, durability is almost same as it seems. As when eren also hardened his hand to prevent war hammer's attack pierce his neck (which is hardened weapon) it did prevent barely. (Note that jaw's different)
Rest i don't think colour is any indication.

Comment: So its just a kind of style? - underwhelming but thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at a [wiki page](https://attackontitan.fandom.com/wiki/Power_of_the_Titans_(Anime)) produced this:

> There are three levels of hardening that have been showed:
>
> The least durable is the Armored Titan's armor-like skin, mostly because of how it spreads across the whole body.
>
> The blue-colored hardening, which can be learnt by all Nine Titans theoretically as mentioned above, is stronger and can be applied onto different body parts like hands, feet, or nape at will.
>
> Although having a different appearance and color, Wall Titans' hardened "wall" skin is likely at this level, for the Colossal Titan could not kick through it. It is also shown that by focusing the hardening on fewer areas will make those parts even stronger.
>
> The strongest is the crystal-like level, which has only seen being used by Female Titan and War Hammer Titan, and it is used to contain its own user inside, for protecting purpose only. Currently, only the Jaw Titan's jaws and claws are seen to be able to penetrate through this crystal-like hardening.

About the War Hammer's appearance, it's probably caused by it's affinity to the Hardening ability.